Change color and symbol simultaneously in a Plotly Scattermapbox
I have a Plotly Scattermapbox that I've embedded in a Dash app. I'm trying to include two separate toggles: one that changes the markers' colors and one that changes their symbols.
Each toggle works fine independently, but if I try to enable both color and symbol simultaneously, the symbols show up while the colors rever to normal.
I want to be able to turn on the symbol and the color at the same time. Is it possible to do so?
import dash
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = px.data.iris()
color_dict = {'versicolor': 'brown', 'setosa': 'orange', 'virginica': 'pink'}
symbol_dict = {'versicolor': 'star', 'setosa': 'circle', 'virginica': 'triangle'}

cmap = df["species"].map(color_dict)
smap = df["species"].map(symbol_dict)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.P("Toggle for the color"),
        dcc.Checklist(
            id="color_toggle",
            options=[{"label": "", "value": True}],
            value=[],
            inline=True
        ),
        html.P("Toggle for the symbol"),
        dcc.Checklist(
            id="symbol_toggle",
            options=[{"label": "", "value": True}],
            value=[],
            inline=True
        ),
        html.Div(
           dcc.Graph(id="chart"),
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("chart", "figure"),
    [Input("color_toggle", "value"),
     Input("symbol_toggle", "value")
     ]
)

def update_fig(cmap_on, smap_on):

    fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df['sepal_width'],
        lon=df['sepal_length'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(color = cmap if cmap_on else None,
                    symbol = smap if smap_on else None,
                    )
        )
    )

    fig.update_layout(height = 750,
                  mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapboxtoken,
        style='light',
        )) 

    fig.update_mapboxes(zoom = 4)

    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)


I don't think this is possible for most symbols. From the docs:

Note that the array marker.color and marker.size are only available for “circle” symbols.

It's not just a problem with your checkboxes - you can't recolor non-circle markers, regardless of how you're trying to do it.
